# When, if ever, should [tag:foo] markup be used in posts on non-Meta sites?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that a user has, while editing some posts on the main site, introduced [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag) markup. Some examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559921/how-do-i-search-and-if-found-update-mysql-database-in-php
- [How can I substitute 'not in' in Hive 0.13 since it is not supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34530918/how-can-i-substitute-not-in-in-hive-0-13-since-it-is-not-supported)
- [Orient db Query for getting Sample db Grateful Dead Concerts data in Jasper Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34525697/orient-db-query-for-getting-sample-db-grateful-dead-concerts-data-in-jasper-repo)

This isn't widely done, and it offends my eyes, but it's not obviously unreasonable. Is using [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag) markup in this way encouraged? Discouraged? Worth editing into a post? Worth editing *out* of a post? I personally don't like this markup being used outside of Meta discussions about tags and am inclined to remove it, but I don't know whether others feel the same.

Comment: I don't really care for it either. I personally don't think it adds any value to the post.

Comment: I've never personally seen this done or any meta discussion about it. But I am with you. I think it distracts from the post. The tags down below where they belong are good enough and shouldn't, imo, be in the post. It doesn't necessarily seem unreasonable for them to be in the body except, again, it seems distracting. I would personally vote to edit them out into plain text and leave a comment for the editor because he simply may think it is correct.

Comment: I can imagine someone choosing this formatting in order to introduce tags to a question that is basically answered mostly by knowledge of the concepts behind those tags. But that doesn't help searchability any, so it's fairly common for those cases to be handled by the hack of adding those tags to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the question since it was me adding tag markup, I was taking the extra time to tag since I thought it will help to embassies the technology in question / answer... I will stop immediately if you feel this is not the correct way.

Comment: Naturally I will edit them out in a couple of days to not invalidate your post.

Comment: I have removed the tag markup, you may consider to edit your post, thanks again.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Thanks. :) I don't see much need to edit my post here - any future readers of this Meta question will probably be savvy enough to look at the revision history of the linked posts once they see that there's no tag markup there.

Comment: Checking my old answer I feel that in some case they where not so bad  example.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34396999/jasperreports-jrxml-file-not-parsed-correctly/34401583#34401583, it was so nice that user could move mouse over xsd to understand what it is, ..... but I will proceed with my clean up...

Comment: @PetterFriberg if you want to use them in your own posts, and think they add value there, I don't think anyone is going to be inclined to stop you. (I certainly won't.) It was just seeing them edited into *other* people's posts that made me take enough notice to bring up on Meta. By all means leave them in your own posts in places where you think they're doing good - you have somewhat more editorial freedom over your own posts than over those of others!

Comment: Ok, one of your example was actually my own post..... (the last one, the answer was mine). In the example in comment the tag markup helped to not also explain was xsd is in the answer, user could hover the xsd or click it to understand ..... anyway message received!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Per [Grace Note](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/146126/grace-note) (a community manager), answering the question [When should we use the [tag] markup in the body of a question on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114860/when-should-we-use-the-tag-markup-in-the-body-of-a-question-on-stack-overflow) on meta.SE:

> There generally isn't a reason to use tags in questions and answers on
>   any main Q&A site. It may happen in comments but it doesn't format
>   there, anyway.
>
> ...
>
> We still allow tag syntax on main sites primarily because of tag
>   wikis.

I completely agree with this...

Comment: Thanks for answer I will edit them out (tomorrow) to not invalidate meta question.

Answer (score 2):

The `[tag:bar]` isn't supported on other markdown implementations but SE's, and it is not included in the CommonMark specifications. If anything, outside SE there isn't any use for this *"extension"* (the HTML specifications define tags, but that's another thing altogether). So, from a strictly semantical point of view, there isn't any use for those outside the Stack Exchange context.

But that isn't what you ask... you want to know if you should use [baz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/baz) outside the meta context. Well, we have a specially designed field to input tags, which is a hint that they don't belong to the body of a question/answer, and since its use is just to link to the question list with that tag, I say that is difficult to surmise a situation where these become essential to make sense of a post.

Comment: That seems like a whole lot of big words to say, "I agree" :P

Comment: @codeMagic I'm afraid that people [would not take me seriously](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CNB5a.png) if I don't D: