# The reputation system makes it challenging to obtain privileges

Tags: discussion

Since Stack Overflow began in 2008, many good questions are already taken or answered by someone a long time ago. The majority of the oldest users secured their questions and subsequent questions are marked for duplication. I get it.

Consider this [NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/218510#218510) question as an example. How could new users grow their reputation in order to obtain privileges and help other users? Points are awarded for duplication, but receive much less attention from queues. This impedes new users' motivation for seeking out unanswered and answered questions.

Many of the hardest questions remain. We know there a lot of duplication, but we don't receive points for marking them as duplicates. We have many questions with unaccepted answers, waiting for them to decide which answer is acceptable can be never-ending process. There should be a feature or privilege that would benefit both old and new users, and keep questions distinct in Stack Overflow communities.

Comment: Reputation is not a game to be won.  Why is this a problem?

Comment: Efficient? Yes. Answer questions, get upvotes. Rep isn't a race. The fact people have years in advance gives them more rep, but doesn't stop you from getting some either

Comment: This is a legitimate question and now is marked as duplication. The result of asking a question is two down-vote. This is not appealing to many of us.

Comment: @jmsweb downvotes on meta don't cost you rep. And this is marked for duplication becausr it has been discussed to death already, and with that in mind, it makes sense to let you see what has been discussed. Duping isn't inherently bad. Anyway... A bit of searching around on meta would have answered your question.

Comment: @jmsweb Speak for yourself please, or at least offer actual data that supports your point.

Comment: @jmsweb Also; you're incorrect regarding `no points are awarded to duplicate a thread`; duplicates are typically down-voted, yes, but the OPs that created them can still earn rep from them, provided they are up-voted, and not deleted.

Comment: I don't want to gas light anything but the response I received from this was disappointing. For sake of SO, I'm delete this post which could had been constructive discussion for future users.

Comment: @jmsweb define "response was disappoint" in your comment.  You seem to have received plenty of feedback via comments and answers explaining.  Or are you simply referring to votes on your question?

Comment: You seem to be lobbying to discontinue "duplicate" as a close-reason for questions and the case is not very compelling.

Comment: Voting irregularities?

Comment: In a sense, git gud. Yes, questions regarding common issues seem to all be asked and answered. Learn from those existing answers and write up a true banger of a question or answer. Why reward wheel-reinvention? There is not much stopping a low-rep user from gaining several thousand points in a short span of time.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Please see [this discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340157/is-editing-technology-names-to-link-to-corresponding-wikipedia-articles-useful) regarding your recent edits.

Answer (score 19):

Your question is based on a single flawed premise—that there is actually a game in Stack Overflow's reputation to be won.

Firstly, there is no "race to the top".  There isn't a reputation game to be won by anyone, whether they started during the private beta in 2008, or 5 years ago, or today.  You don't win anything by being first.

And even if reputation was a game—no matter what the rules were, you have a long way to go.  The current leader in reputation, Jon Skeet, has well over 900K reputation.  Given the current rep cap of 200 rep per day, it would take 12.5 years to catch Jon if he stopped earning rep today (although with bounties and accepted answers, which are exempt from the cap, you could do it faster).

Although, in fairness to your question, you are simply in the same situation as if you were a late-comer to a popular MMO game.  The early adopters are going to have more resources than you do, simply because they were first.  You just have to try to work your way up the ladder slowly.

But, in the end, the point is you earn rep the same as all of us did.... by asking and answering good questions.  There are plenty of questions that need answers (both old and new).  And even old answered questions might need new answers based on new versions of languages. Stop worrying about the people who earned rep before you and go find questions you can answer that haven't been answered before, or have outdated answers.

Comment: SO is a MMO??? How can I change the my characters appearance?

Comment: @PierreLebon [By putting on a hat](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The hat merchant is too HightLevel for me, I must kill 75 340 285 Boar to hit level max.